# Power supply protection

Tags: voltage-regulator, circuit-protection, linear-regulator, over-voltage-protection

I'm trying to create a power supply protection (overvoltage, undervoltage, reverse polarity) for a ±33 V, 7 mA power supply for an op-amp.

The opamp would be powered by a lab supply in theory. So the idea is to protect it in case the operator hasn't set the voltage right, the protection will correct it so it's never above +33V (and -33V for the other rail).

Second point, it would be nice to have: if the current is rising above the set limit, the protection would cap it at chosen value.

Third protection needed: if the operator plugs the cable the wrong way, the opamp is ok.

Do you have any suggestions? My system must withstand ±50 V, about 10 mA, reverse polarity (and no shut down, caused by a fuse for example, would be a massive plus).

Comment: What you have shown in your picture is not going to work at all. If you have moved away from that then don't show it because it will melt when the input voltage is negative. Show the circuit that you are working on and ditch the picture of what you are not working on.

Comment: Instead of focusing your question on what doesn't work and what you don't want, explain more what provides the power and what circuit you're trying to protect and from what. The solution can be as simple as a couple of regulators. Under reverse polarity there will be no operation so "no shutdown" is then no option unless you design for both polarities (use a bridge rectifier + smoothing caps). I see many beginners dive into the implementation (circuit and components they want to use) too soon before even getting clear what is needed and what type of circuits can do that.

Comment: Why do you think you need a current limiter? Yes, once a current limiter starts operating the voltage drops in order to maintain ohms law and the laws of physics; you can't have an output voltage that remains at a constant value when a current limiter is starting to kick in. So, why do you need a current limiter?

Comment: @Andyaka Well if i want to protrect my Opamp power supply, shouldn't I have to protect it from as many fault as i can? In case of a short-circuit for example.

Comment: And what might be the cause of the short circuit that would still allow the circuit to actually carry on working?

Comment: *shouldn't I have to protect it from as many fault as i can?* No, you add the protection **that is needed**. So you first have to decide what is needed. What can happen? Don't say: *the supply can be shorted* because then I say: put it in a plastic box so no-one can touch the circuit or do you have small children walking around that constantly try to short the opamp's supplies when you're not looking? Also realize that most voltage regulators have short circuit protection build in.

Comment: Realize that circuits that have protection against "everything" can still have some weaknesses like me smashing them with a hammer. Realize that circuits that have protection against "everything" can get too complex to work properly. Realize that the protection might cost more than using a **socket** for the opamp so that if the opamp breaks, you can easily replace it.

Comment: Hum... i have some difficulties to explain myself per text and not in my native language.
At first when I wanted to use a fuse. When a short happens (or something else that makes the current rise over the OpAmp's current limit) my opamp doesn't fry. But the issue with a fuse is that you have to replace it. I've heard of PTC that are better because they reset themselves after some time.
But my idea was to have something quick. If the operator sees that there is a fault, he removes the cause and the circuit can "instantly " go on/ I hope my goal is more clear now.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I edited my post. Is it more clear now?

Comment: *Third protection needed: if the operator plugs the cable the wrong way, the opamp is ok.* Connectors exist that prevent the cables from being plugged in the wrong way. Still unclear if the 50 V supply is short circuit proof, if it is then place diodes on the PCB that short the supply when it has reverse polarity. The other issues can be addressed by using voltage regulator ICs.

Comment: The "physical" protection is a great idea. But the cables in the lab are all round. And i can't get special cables just for this application. Otherwise it would have been perfecct.

I've been browsing the internet for hours looking for ICs that respect my specs. For the positive voltage I find many. But the negative voltage is black magic, I find nothing that goes as high as -50 V... I only found two references that reach -30 V. Which is why i came here to ask for more basic circuitry. I tried "negative overvoltage lockout" ,"negative overvoltage protection", etc

Answer (score -2):

Use Nexperia PESD1CAN for transient over voltage event:

https://www.nexperia.com/products/esd-protection-tvs-filtering-and-signal-conditioning/automotive-esd-protection-and-tvs/lin-can-fd-flexray/PESD1CAN.html

They are excellent and I successfully tested them with an EFT tester.

They are automotive qualified and cost nothing.

---

For reverse polarity use diode S1M

---

For under voltage use a lot of capacitors on the regulated output of your regulator

---

Order:

PESD1CAN TVS comes first and then the S1M diode.

If you switch them, the diode will blow at the first over voltage event.

Comment: Components for transient protection cannot protect against permanent overvoltage. If you apply +50V here the TVS will burn up. It needs to be a (resettable) fuse here, but at a 10mA rating that is no trivial case.

Comment: You probably mean a TL431. I do not see how using a TL431 is more convenient than using a simple pass-regulator (the TL431 is a shunt regulator).